# How to use vimception?

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to make vimception work for my ipython notebook. Following the instructions, I put the corresponding files in ~/.ipython/extensions/vimception.

However, whenever I use %load_ext vimception, I receive the following error message:

[image]

And after that, none of the vim key bindings seem to work. I am currently use a Macbook pro, but I experienced the same problem with Windows 8. Can anybody helps me out here?

BTW, is there a help file for vimception about the key bindings work? I try to use i to get into the insert mode and [ESC] to get out of it, but nothing seems to work within a cell.

Thanks!

p.s.: I use Chrome as my browser, and I got the following in my developer console.

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you open the Developer Console and check for any javasrcipt errors as the message indicates? On Chrome press `Ctrl + Shift + i`

Comment: No. He is using a Mac so the shortcut is `Cmd+Shift+j`.

Comment: thanks for the replies! I have updated my post, which included the output in the developer console.